# Zero-inflated ordered logit model interpretation

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, stata

Consider this Stata code and selected results:

```
use https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsb2, clear

generate honcomp = (write >=60)
logit honcomp female read science

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -115.64441
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -84.558481
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -80.491449
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -80.123052
Iteration 4:   log likelihood = -80.118181
Iteration 5:   log likelihood = -80.11818
```

This is a listing of the log likelihoods at each iteration. (Remember that logistic regression uses maximum likelihood, which is an iterative procedure.)  The first iteration (called iteration 0) is the log likelihood of the “null” or “empty” model; that is, a model with no predictors. At the next iteration, the predictor(s) are included in the model.  At each iteration, the log likelihood increases because the goal is to maximize the log likelihood.  When the difference between successive iterations is very small,  the model is said to have “converged”, iteration is stopped and the results are displayed.

The above is from https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/output/logistic-regression-analysis/.

There is also an option of fitting a zero-inflated ordered logit model.

. ziologit tobacco education income i.female, inflate(income education i.parent)

```
Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -15977.364  (not concave)
Iteration 1:   log likelihood =  -13149.83  (not concave)
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -12467.245
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -11039.218
Iteration 4:   log likelihood = -9929.2298
Iteration 5:   log likelihood = -9715.1143
Iteration 6:   log likelihood = -9703.2464
Iteration 7:   log likelihood = -9703.2168
Iteration 8:   log likelihood = -9703.2168
```

This output is from https://www.stata.com/new-in-stata/zero-inflated-ordered-logit/.

There appears to be one model computation being performed here, since there is only one iteration output.

1. Is there just one model being fitted here that provide simultaneously all the coefficients for the tobacco and inflate portions? If this is correct how is this done?
2. What relevance is “not concave”? Does it matter if it is or is not concave?
3. In the link, there is also /cut1, /cut2 and /cut3. What do these represent?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. But you say *... since GLMs are based on exponential distributions*, which is a misconception! GLM's are based on **exponential famileis**, something entirely different from exponential distributions.

Comment: @kjetil-b-halvorsen amended as per your helpful comment. It is more from a practical perspective, say when constructing models, of how the iteration output can be used. Perhaps there is some theory or heuristic to guide practice? That the iterations are individually listed, suggests utility. The final log likelihood is listed by Stata twice, once in the final iteration and underneath on a line of its own.

Comment: Failure to converge often indicates a problematic model and slow convergence sometimes indicates an awkward model, but otherwise the number of iterations is not diagnostic of anything other than what it is.

Comment: @Nick-Cox one minus the final converged value divided by the initial value is the calculation for McFadden’s Pseudo R-Squared, suggesting only the converged value matters (at least for this particular Pseudo R-Squared statistic). If there is not practical use of the iterations it may still be educational to get more understanding of specific examples, perhaps of slow convergence highlighting an awkward model.

Comment: The main use of the iteration log is to show that Stata is working on your behalf, when it is.

Comment: The ziologit has a single likelihood that represents the likelihood of all the parameters being estimated. There are not two likelihoods for the two portions of the model. There is a single estimation procedure over all the parameters. This is why at each iteration you see only a single likelihood. This is done by writing down the likelihood for all the parameters in a single expression and maximizing this value. The two components of the model are estimated simultaneously and depend on each other.

Comment: This is confusing to me.  An ordinary ordinal logistic model automatically handles any magnitude of zero inflation.  You'll just see a big jump between two of the intercept parameter values.

Comment: @Noah that was exactly the kind of information was after. This means that within the single estimation procedure, each observation (row) is used twice. I found question 3. from other Stata documentation. Do you the answer to question 2. or an R package with the equivalent function? Can accept as an answer.

Comment: @Frank-Harrell the ziologit command is new in Stata 17, which is the latest version. According to the example (unfortunately the tobacco data they give is fictitious) it shows that with increased income you are less likely to smoke cigarettes, but conditional on if you do smoke, then you are more likely to smoke more cigarettes than lower income smokers. You can use a potentially different set of predictors for the logit and ordered logit model, which is presumably an advantage as offers flexibility. First time have seen this technique so am open to any critique.

Comment: Very interesting.  You can do that with the old partial proportional odds model too (e.g., VGAM package in R).

Comment: P.S. That would be the constrained partial proportional odds model, with prop. odds for the non-zero levels of Y and a special effect for Y=0.  This doubles the number of regression coefficients as with the model you discussed.  It's more general than zero inflation.

Comment: @Frank-Harrell the January 2010 JSS paper explained some fundamentals of VGAM. Is quite advanced, and will read around the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zero-inflated original logit has a single likelihood that represents the likelihood of all the parameters being estimated. There are not two likelihoods for the two portions of the model. There is a single estimation procedure over all the parameters. This is why at each iteration you see only a single likelihood. This is done by writing down the likelihood for all the parameters in a single expression and maximizing this value. The two components of the model are estimated simultaneously and depend on each other. It's not the case that each unit is used twice; each unit contributes exactly once to the likelihood.

The /cut1, /cut2, and /cut3 in the output are the cutpoints in the ordinal logit model. See `help ologit` for more details. These are the equivalents of the intercept in a binary logistic regression. The probability that the linear predictor plus error falls between the cutpoints is the probability of receiving the corresponding value of the outcome (given that you are not in the inflation group).